# Ruby Dump Function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, dump

I am working through Learn Ruby the Hard Way Exercise 39 and it asks me to use the Dump function to list out everything in my hash. I've searched and used the ideas found in the [Ruby Documentation on Marshal Dump](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) but believe I am writing the syntax incorrectly as I receive an undefined no method error even though (I think) I've defined it:
ex39f.rb:41:in `<main>': undefined method`dump' for Dict:Module (NoMethodError)

Would anyone have insight into the syntax/way to organize the function so that I can dump everything out in the hash?

The module which houses the hashes and other methods is as follows. You will find my dump function at the bottom:

```
module Dict
    #Creates a new function that makes a Dictionary. This is done through creating the 
    # aDict variable that has an array in which num_buckets array is placed inside.
    # These buckets will be used to hold the contents of the Dict and later aDict.length
    # is used to find out how many buckets there are.  
    def Dict.new(num_buckets=256)
        # Initializes a Dict with the given number of buckets.
        aDict = []
        (0...num_buckets).each do |i|
            aDict.push([])
        end

        return aDict
    end

    # Converts a string to a number using the bult-in Ruby 'hash' function
    # Once I have a number for the key, I use the % operator and aDict.length to get a 
    # bucket where the remainder can go. 
    def Dict.hash_key(aDict, key)
        # Given a key this will create a number and then convert it to an index for the
        # aDict's buckets
        return key.hash % aDict.length
    end

    # Uses hash_key to find a bucket that the key could be in. Using bucket_id I can get 
    # the bucket where the key could be. By using the modulus operator I know it will fit
    # into the aDict array of 256.
    def Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)
        # Given a key, find the bucket where it would go.
        bucket_id = Dict.hash_key(aDict, key)
        return aDict[bucket_id]
    end

    # Uses get_slot to get the (i, k, v) and returns the v (value) only. 
    def Dict.get_slot(aDict, key, default=nil)
        # Returns the index, key and value of a slot found in a bucket.
        bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)

        bucket.each_with_index do |kv, i|
         k, v = kv
         if key == k
            return i, k, v
         end
        end

        return -1, key, default
    end

    def Dict.get(aDict, key, default=nil)
        # Gets the value in a bucket for the given key or the default.
        i, k, v = Dict.get_slot(aDict, key, default=default)
        return v
    end

    def assert(aDict, key)
        unless aDict == key
            puts "The key cannot be found in the dictionary"
        end
    end

    # Sets a key/value pair by getting the bucket and appending the new (key, value) to it.
    # First you have to get the bucket, see if the key already exists, if it does then
    # replace it, if it doesn't get replaced then append it. 
    def Dict.set(aDict, key, value)
        # Sets the key to the value, replacing any existing value.
        bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)
        i, k, v = Dict.get_slot(aDict, key)

        if i >= 0
            bucket[i] = [key, value]
        else
            bucket.push([key, value])
        end
    end

    # Deletes a key by getting the bucket, searching for key in it and deleting it form the
    # array. 
    def Dict.delete(aDict, key)
        # Deletes the given key from the Dict.
        bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)

        (0...bucket.length).each do |i|
            k, v = bucket[i]
            if key == k
                bucket.delete_at(i)
                break
            end
        end
    end

    # goes through each slot in each bucket and prints out what's in the Dict. 
    #def Dict.list(aDict)
        # Prints out what's in the Dict.
    #   aDict.each do |bucket|
    #       if bucket
    #           bucket.each {|k, v| puts k, v}
    #       end
    #   end
    #end

    def Dict.dump(aDict)
        #Prints out each bucket so you can debug it.
        Marshal.dump(aDict)
    end
end
```

The script I am trying to call the dump function in is as follows:

```
require './dict.rb'

include Dict

# create a mapping of state to abbreviation

    states = Dict.new()
    Dict.set(states, 'Oregon', 'OR')
    Dict.set(states, 'Florida', 'FL')
    Dict.set(states, 'California', 'CA')
    Dict.set(states, 'New York', 'NY')
    Dict.set(states, 'Michigan', 'MI')

    # create a basic set of states and some cities in them
    cities = Dict.new()
    Dict.set(cities, 'CA', 'San Francisco')
    Dict.set(cities, 'MI', 'Detroit')
    Dict.set(cities, 'FL', 'Jacksonville')

    # add some more cities
    Dict.set(cities, 'NY', 'New York')
    Dict.set(cities, 'OR', 'Portland')

    # puts out some cities
    puts '-' * 10
    puts "NY State has: #{Dict.get(cities, 'NY')}"
    puts "OR State has: #{Dict.get(cities, 'OR')}"

    # puts some states
    puts '-' * 10
    puts "Michigan's abbreviation is: #{Dict.get(states, 'Michigan')}"
    puts "Florida's abbreviation is: #{Dict.get(states, 'Florida')}"

    # do it by using the state then cities dict
    puts '-' * 10
    puts "Michigan has: #{Dict.get(cities, Dict.get(states, 'Michigan'))}"
    puts "Florida has: #{Dict.get(cities, Dict.get(states, 'Florida'))}"

    # puts every state abbreviation
    puts '-' * 10
    #Dict.list(states)
    Dict.dump(states)

    # puts every city in state
    puts '-' * 10
    Dict.dump(cities)
    #Dict.list(cities)

    puts '-' * 10
    # by default ruby says "nil" when something isn't in there
    state = Dict.get(states, 'Texas')

    if !state
        puts "Sorry, no Texas."
    end

    # default values using ||= with the nil result
    city = Dict.get(cities, 'TX', 'Does Not Exist')
    puts "The city for the state 'TX' is: #{city}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit more research and returned to how I tried to solve this problem the first time with some confirmation from another resource I found online.

On the Module Dict I added the following:

```
Dict.dump(aDict) 
  aDict.each do |bucket|
     puts bucket
  end
end
```

On the script I was using I used the following call:

```
Dict.dump(cities) 
Dict.dump(states)
```

For those who are wondering, cities/states are the hash values I created at the start of the script. The buckets represent where the key and value for their hash is stored. Therefore I am passing the hash (i.e. cities and states variables) into the function Dict.dump(hash) to dump i.e. print out all the buckets that store their keys and values.